# Choosing dynamically method based on input

Tags: java, spring-boot, runtime

I would want to choose method from service class based on input to `URI`.

I have controller method that fetch category name:

```
@GetMapping("/{category}/ranking")
    public Map<String, Integer> getRankingForCategory(@PathVariable String category) {
        return categorizedBooksRanking.getRankingForCategory(category);
    }
```

Based on it, I want to choose one of my 5 methods:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypes;

imports...

import static bookstore.scraper.JSoupConnector.connect;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class CategorizedBookService {

    private final EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService;
    private final MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.romances}")
    private String romancesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.biographies}")
    private String biographiesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.crime}")
    private String crimeCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.guides}")
    private String guidesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.fantasy}")
    private String fantasyCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.romances}")
    private String romancesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.biographies}")
    private String biographiesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.crime}")
    private String crimeCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.guides}")
    private String guidesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.fantasy}")
    private String fantasyCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Autowired
    public CategorizedBookService(EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService, MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService) {
        this.empikBookService = empikBookService;
        this.merlinFetchingBookService = merlinFetchingBookService;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromRomanceCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(romancesCategoryEmpikURL, romancesCategoryMerlinURL);
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromFantasyCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(fantasyCategoryEmpikURL, fantasyCategoryMerlinURL);
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromCrimeCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(crimeCategoryEmpikURL, crimeCategoryMerlinURL);
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromGuidesCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(guidesCategoryEmpikURL, guidesCategoryMerlinURL);
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(biographiesCategoryEmpikURL, biographiesCategoryMerlinURL);
    }

    private Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFrom(String bookStoreEmpikURL, String bookStoreMerlinURL) {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(bookStoreEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(bookStoreMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }
}
```

So that in another service:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getRankingForCategory(String category) {
        ....

        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory(); // here should be corresponding the method from CategorizedBookService`
...
}
```

e.g If I put `biography/ranking` then method which I placed at the top should be present.

If I put `crime/ranking` then method `get15BooksFromCrimeCategory` should be present.

Is there any way to do it? To choose method at runtime?